# Separation of variables in an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I am looking for the function equivalent of Sympy's function: as_independent (*deps, **hint) in Mathematica. The function naively separates an expression into arguments that are not dependent on deps. This operation does not work for non-commutative terms, since they cannot always be separated out.

For example, let us consider the expression

```
F[x_,t_,a_] = Cos[2*t] Sin[5 x] Exp[-2 t] t^3 a
```

We observe that $f(x,t,a) = T(t)*X(x)*A(a)$ and thus the equation is separable in its arguments $x,t,a$. Suppose I would like to separate the equation in its arguments x and t. For argument t, this operation should return $X(x)*A(a)$ and $T(t)$

> 1. `Sin[5x] a`
> 2. `Cos[2*t] Exp[-2t] t^3`

For argument x the operation should return $T(t)*A(a)$ and $X(x)$

> 1. `Cos[2*t] Exp[-2t] t^3 a`
> 2. `Sin[5x]`

Is this possible in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that you are giving a single term, whose `Head` is `Times`,

```
asIndependent[prod_, var_] := 
 Times @@@ 
  SortBy[GatherBy[List @@ prod, FreeQ[var] ], Not@*FreeQ[var]];
```

I wish there were an option to `GatherBy` that would make it sort by the same function, but so be it - I had to use `SortBy` as well so that the return order would be consistent.

```
asIndependent[Cos[2*t] Sin[5 x] Exp[-2 t] t^3 a, t]
asIndependent[Cos[2*t] Sin[5 x] Exp[-2 t] t^3 a, x]
asIndependent[Cos[2*t] Sin[5 x] Exp[-2 t] t^3 a, a]
(* {a Sin[5 x], E^(-2 t) t^3 Cos[2 t]} *)
(* {a E^(-2 t) t^3 Cos[2 t], Sin[5 x]} *)
(* {E^(-2 t) t^3 Cos[2 t] Sin[5 x], a} *)
```

**Edit** I wanted to make the function as close to the [python function](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.as_independent) as possible, so I've adjusted it so it will work with any object whose `Head` is `Plus` or `Times`

```
asIndependent[expr_, var_] := If[MemberQ[{Plus, Times}, Head[expr]],
  Head[expr] @@@ 
   SortBy[GatherBy[List @@ expr, FreeQ[var]], Not@*FreeQ[var]]]
```

The results above are identical, and we can do the following test cases as well

```
asIndependent[x + x y, x]
asIndependent[x + x y, y]
asIndependent[2 x Sin[x] + y + x + z, x]
asIndependent[(x - n1) (x - y), x]
(* {x + x y} *)
(* {x, x y} *)
(* {y + z, x + 2 x Sin[x]} *)
(* {(-n1 + x) (x - y)} *)
```

The only thing I haven't done yet is to make it take multiple variables, like `asIndependent[2 x Sin[x] + y + x + z,{x,y}]` - it shouldn't be too hard but it will make it more complicated I think.